# If/Else statement not working, giving undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project, and I need the English version of countries' names. I'm trying to have an if/else statement that will give the English spelling when the non-English spelling of a country is given, but it's not working. I would really appreciate any help or advice on why I am having this issue. Thank you!

```
let countryName;
  if (country === 'Shqipëria' || 'hqipëria') {
    let countryName ='Albania';
  }
  else if (country === 'Hayastán' || 'hayastán') {
   let countryName ='Armenia';
  }

 ...

  else if (country === 'Italia' || 'italia') {
   let countryName ='Italy';
  }

 ...

  else if (country === 'Türkiye' || 'türkiye') {
   let countryName = 'Turkey';
  }
 else if (country === 'Ukraїna' || 'Україна' || 'ukraїna' || 'yкраїна') {
   let countryName = 'Ukraine';
  }
 else {
    let countryName = country;
    }


  console.log(countryName)
  console.log(country)
```

`console.log(country)` gives Italia, but `console.log(countryName)` is undefined.

I have also tried doing this:

```
const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState('')
  if (country === 'Shqipëria' || 'hqipëria') {
    setCountryName('Albania');
  }
  else if (country === 'Hayastán' || 'hayastán') {
   setCountryName('Armenia');
  }

 ...

  else if (country === 'Italia' || 'italia') {
   setCountryName('Italy');
  }

 ...

  else if (country === 'Türkiye' || 'türkiye') {
   setCountryName('Turkey');
  }
 else if (country === 'Ukraїna' || 'Україна' || 'ukraїna' || 'yкраїна') {
   setCountryName('Ukraine');
  }
 else {
    setCountryName(country);
    }


  console.log(countryName)
  console.log(country)
```

But this was giving me an error stating `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Comment: Every time you use `let`, you're defining a new variable at that scope which ends when you reach the closing `}`. In each of your if/else blocks, you're defining and initializing a new variable for that block which shadows the one on top then immediately gets thrown away. Just remove the `let` so you can assign to that top variable.

Comment: And every time you use setState, it will re-render the component which make setState again, so you get the second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in other answers your conditions only contain one equality check, so it wold always return true because a string's value by-itself is truthy, so you never get passed the first condition. for simplifying `if` statements, you can use the `includes` method. for example:

```
if (['Ukraїna','Україна','ukraїna','yкраїна'].includes(country))
```

and definitely declare country variable once & re-assign it in every condition.

```
let countryName;

if (...) {
  countryName = "x"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancerning your first code: countryname shouldn't be declared many times
so your code should be like this:

```
let countryName;
if (country === 'Shqipëria' || country === 'hqipëria') {
    countryName ='Albania';
}
else if (country === 'Hayastán' || country === 'hayastán') {
    countryName ='Armenia';
}
else if (country === 'Italia' || country === 'italia') {
    countryName ='Italy';
}
else if (country === 'Türkiye' || country === 'türkiye') {
   countryName = 'Turkey';
}
 else if (country === 'Ukraїna' || country === 'Україна' || country === 'ukraїna' || country === 'yкраїна') {
   countryName = 'Ukraine';
}
 else {
    countryName = country;
}

console.log(countryName);
console.log(country);
```

Also, you should use

```
if(variable === 'value' || variable === 'value')
```

instead of

```
if (variable === 'value' || 'value')
```